# Always On Cluster, Network Problem, make failover or disconnections for nodes

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

have a nice day, I have a cluster sharing the same quorum resource, this quorum is a server with 2 share folders, one for SQL Always on Cluster, and other for SAP Always On Cluster,

I have lot´s of connection problems, and I check all settings on the hardware for those 2 Always on cluster, (VmWare Infra).

My question is is or it's not recommended this architecture, 2 Always on cluster in the same quorum server, even if I have 2 different shared resources for every cluster?

My concern is according to quorum:

1. Is a Windows Server (virtual machine), is necessary update for security reasons.
2. If I lost connection or shutdown the server, 2 clusters will be affected
3. Every cluster will fight for quorum resources

I need to know the best experience, and try to fix this, Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is is or it's not recommended this architecture, 2 Always on cluster in the same quorum server, even if I have 2 different shared resources for every cluster?

It's perfectly fine to use the same base share for multiple clusters so long as whatever is hosting that share has availability that meets your needs. Generically, the witness should not need to be arbitrated unless there is some sort of issue, which would hopefully be a rare event.

> Is a Windows Server (virtual machine), is necessary update for security reasons.

I would keep it updated, if that's your question.

> If I lost connection or shutdown the server, 2 clusters will be affected

I can't speak for SAP clusters as I don't know what they are or how they work, but for Windows clusters if you lose connection or the server is shut down, then arbitration for the witness will fail. This will only affect you if you need to arbitrate for some reason. If you're rebooting for patches or updates and the clusters using the share are healthy, there shouldn't be an issue.

> Every cluster will fight for quorum resources

Every file share witness is a different resource. If that cluster has a need to arbitrate for the resource, it will, but shouldn't affect any other cluster or FSW on that share.